# Generating Sub Reports for Each Cashier and Grand Total For each day

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report getting data from SQL Server. I want to generate GroupReport Total and also Generate Grand Total Report

I have been able to generate the report from SQL, the following are the fields i have: Item_Name, qty, Price, Amount

I have created a Formular to sum all the amount which the total will give me the GrandTotal

But for each subreport, i want to get the total amount too but this seems to be operating in a running total form.

Below is what i am getting now.

```
CashierA
OrderDate        Item     qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-24       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-24       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-24       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        22,000

CashierB
OrderDate        Item     qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-24       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-24       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-24       fish      2   2,000    4,000

sub_Total        42,000

Day_Total        42,000

CashierA
OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-25       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-25       beans     2   4,000    8,000
2019-07-25       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        62,000

CashierB
OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-25       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-25       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-25       fish      2   4,000    8,000

sub_Total        86,000
Day_Total        86,000

GrandTotal     86,000
```

tonumber({DTtablesales.Amount})

The Below is what I want

```
CashierA
OrderDate        Item     qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-24       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-24       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-24       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        22,000

CashierB
OrderDate        Item     qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-24       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-24       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-24       fish      2   2,000    4,000

sub_Total        20,000

Day_Total        42,000

CashierA
OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-25       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-25       beans     2   4,000    8,000
2019-07-25       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        20,000

CashierB
OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-25       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-25       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-25       fish      2   4,000    8,000

sub_Total        24,000

Day_Total        44,000

GrandTotal     86,000
```

Note that the GrandTotal is a TotalRunning Field calculating sum(Amount)

My problem is getting the sub-total for each Cashier, get it reset when calling another cashier details for that particular date and the total should be calculated for that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the results desired by using the appropriate grouping levels and summary fields as well.

The top most grouping level would be "Order Date".  And then below that you would group by "Cashier".

Then insert the "Amount" field into the Details section of your report.  Right click the field for "Amount" in the report designer and click on "Insert > Summary".  You should then see the Insert Summary Dialog Box on the screen.  Check the check box for "Add to all group levels" and this will insert summary fields into each Group Footer section and your Report Footer section.  The summary fields in each Cashier group footer should reflect the total sales for each cashier for a single order date.  The Order Date group footer will reflect the total sales for that date across all cashiers, and the Report Footer section will reflect the total sales across all order dates included in the report's database/dataset.

I would also recommend you put a Record Selection formula on the report to allow the user to choose a date range or a single date using the Order Date field.  This can be built into the report using either your SQL code or Parameter fields in the report itself.

Answer (score 0):

On the subtotal field use the Edit Running Total and reset at the appropriate group.

[image]

Comment: I can generate all the reports, Issues is that, if it wants to generate, it will generate report for let us say, a cashier all dates before going to next date

Comment: Based the output you say you want then you need to add a reset on the change in day on the subtotal field.  If you need something else then please revise your output so I can help.